# Fluent NHibernate - Map 2 Identical classes to same table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, readonly

I've seen this (unanswered) question asked once before, but in a different context.  I'm looking to have two domain objects map to the same table, WITHOUT a discriminator.  The two classes are:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ReadOnlyCategory ParentCategory { get; private set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ReadOnlyCategory
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }
    public virtual ReadOnlyCategory ParentCategory { get; private set; }
}
```

The main difference is that all public properties of ReadOnlyCategory are read-only.  My idea here is that I want all users of this class to know that they should only mess with the category they are currently 'looking' at, and not any other categories in the hierarchy.  (I've left off other properties regarding the subcategories.)

Clearly, in the database, Category and ReadOnlyCategory are the same thing, and NHibernate should treat them very similarly when persisting them.  There are three problems wrapped into one here:

1) How do I do the mapping?

2) When instantiating the objects, how do I control whether I instantiate Category or ReadOnlyCategory?

3) When persisting the objects, will the mapping be smart enough, or do I need to use an extensibility point here?

Any pointers on how I can get this to happen?

(Or am I crazy?)

Comment: Your readonlycategory class looks exactly the same to me as the category class...

Comment: public virtual string Name { get; set; } is read/write vs the ReadOnly version.

Comment: If "clearly, in the database Category and ReadOnlyCategory are the same thing'. them they are the same thing.  How can you, or anyone else tell the difference, and so how do you expect nhibernate to tell the difference?  Same data is the same thing.   Not much getting around that...

Comment: I disagree.  The same data can be used in different ways by anything that uses it, especially if the data is used in different contexts.  Here, a parent category *is* different from a child category, even if they both represent the same concept.

Comment: Sure, but NHibernate is a persistence platform, it does not "use" data.  In order to control the *use* context via the *persistence* platform, there must be something available in the persistence attributes to interpret that context, i.e a "discriminator" concept.  Given a readonly attribute, but an identical set of data, what basis exists for NHibernate to correctly select a subset of that data?  The data itself provides no context for how you intend it to be used, your context is introduced externally to NHIbernate's mechanisms which are based on the data persistence pattern, not "intent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like wrong object model design to me. I don't see a good reason to introduce a new class just for authorisation reasons (whether user allowed to modify a given category object?). You may as well use one class and throw for example InvalidOperationException if an end user is not supposed to modify a category.

Comment: The intention here is that NO ONE can edit the parent category, so it's not a matter of authorization.  Plus, why throw an exception if I can try to design it right?  For example, see the ReadOnlyCollection<T> in .NET.

Comment: I prefer to keep my design as simple as possible. I'm afraid I have burnt my fingers badly on an object model that had both a set of read-only interfaces and modifiable interfaces. It quickly ended up with unnecessary complexity, having to support two class or interface hierarchies. The right design in that case was not do it, for sake of simplicity and maintainability. 

As far as ReadOnlyCollection<T> is concerned, could you point me to a read-only variant of the .NET collection interfaces? Event the read-only ICollection interface was replaced with the non read-only ICollection<T>...

Comment: I think that I agree with you.  I've done a lot of searching online, and there are few who attempt this, and I haven't come across anyone who has succeeded.  (Although I think it's possible using calculated discriminators.)  Doing something like this is perhaps too complicated and may not even be the responsibility of the Domain.